# How do you write this sql query in laravel 5.4?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

```
        $user= Select from user where 'email' = $email AND 'specialty' =null OR 'address' = null OR 'country' =null OR 'state' = null;
```

This is the code i have but its not working properly. What i want is to return the row if  any of the stated columns has its value as null.

```
    $doctor= Doctor::where('email',$email)->where(function ($query) {
            $query->orWhere('state','=','')
                  ->orWhere('country','=','')
                  ->orWhere('address','=','')
                  ->orWhere('specialty','=','');
        })->get();
```

Comment: See the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first - in SQL to filter by `NULL` one should be using `where x IS NOT NULL`.

For the laravel part, Eloquent has a `whereNull` method, see more: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries

So your eloquent code should look somehing like:

```
$doctor= Doctor::where('email',$email)->where(function ($query) {
        $query->orWhereNull('state')
              ->orWhereNull('country')
              ->orWhereNull('address')
              ->orWhereNull('specialty');
    })->get();
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I had no idea there was an orWhereNull() function. I'v literary spent hours on this.

Comment: No problem, I am glad I could help.